# How do I set up databinder dispatch to use in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, databinder

I want to write some simple HTTP requests in Scala, but the Databinder Dispatch library only has instructions for sbt. As I'm a relative Eclipse newbie, can someone provide instructions on how I use it in my Scala project in Eclipse? 
I'm using Scala 2.9.0final. If it's incompatible with Dispatch, is there an alternative HTTP request library?

http://dispatch.databinder.net/Try+Dispatch.html

Thanks!

Comment: I use Dispatch with Scala 2.9.0, and have no problem of compatibility !

Comment: This work on 2.9.0: http://aloiscochard.blogspot.com/2011/05/simple-rest-web-service-client-in-scala.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you have linked to has instructions for trying out Dispatch using the sbt console. It is much easier to just do that on the command line, although if you are convinced to do this with Eclipse you can [read your integration options](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/IntegrationSupport#Eclipse).

If you want to set up a project and write some code that can be compiled that uses Dispatch, you should follow [this guide](http://dispatch-classic.databinder.net/Project+Setup.html).

Which shows you how to pull in dispatch as a dependency with either Maven or sbt. The main thing is that you want the dispatch + dependencies jars on your project classpath in Eclipse before you can start playing with it - sbt makes this easy in Scala and Maven for Java. So you should look around for how to do that in Eclipse to see your options.

Comment: Thanks, I got it working using these instructions, plus setting up my project as an sbt project and then importing that in to Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Dispath is build on top of Apache [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/) which is pure Java library (so can be used from Scala). But if you want to use Dispatch, you can:

1. Git clone the example
2. Install sbt
3. Run `sbt update`
4. Look into `lib_managed/scala_${version}/compile` dir
5. Write a sample scala script Script.scala:

   ```
   import dispatch._
   val h = new Http
   val req = url("http://www.scala-lang.org/")
   val handler = req >>> System.out
   h(handler)
   h(url("http://www.scala-lang.org/") >>> System.out)
   ```
6. Run a script with proper class path. On linux you can do

   ```
   scala -cp `echo lib_managed/scala_${version}/compile/*.jar | sed 's/ /:/g'` Script.scala
   ```
7. Enjoy!)