# Java/Scala | Log into website

Tags: scala

I have a problem..
I want to download to XML some info from website ( this I know how to do ), i know how to dl info from website but problem is when first
i need to log in.

Its part of code:

```
 <form method="post" action="logowanie.php">
  <table class="center">
   <tr>
    <td><label for="username">Login:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="username" value=""></td>
    <td rowspan="2"><div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="OK" name="submit"></div></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><label for="password">Hasło:</label></td>
    <td><input type="password" name="password" value=""></td>
```

I need to some how enter username password and press button submit.
Any ideas , code samples how to do it ? 
Thanks very much.

Im doing it in Java/Scala.

Comment: What is the mechanism of authentication on that site? Cookie, digest, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the Apache `HttpClient` would work, using it from Scala is unidiomatic and verbose,  and the [Dispatch](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Dispatch.html) library provides a nice Scala wrapper that lets you write much more concise code. You could use it like this:

```
import dispatch._

val u = url("https://site.com/logowanie.php")
val info = Seq("username" -> "me", "password" -> "secret")

val client = new Http
client(u << info >>> System.out)
```

This example would simply print the response, but you can easily provide more sophisticated ways of handling the response, and your `client` now holds the cookies you need to continue interacting with the site.

Here's a more complex example that I've used to log in to a system that required me to pick up a generated identifier from the form before logging in:

```
import dispatch._
import dispatch.jsoup.JSoupHttp._

val u = url("https://myuni.edu/something/login")
val info = Seq(
  "username"  -> "me",
  "password"  -> "secret",
  "warn"      -> "true",
  "submit"    -> "LOGIN",
  "execution" -> "e1s1",
  "_eventId"  -> "submit"
)

val client = new Http
val id = client(u </> (_.select("input[name=lt]").first.attr("value")))
client(u << info :+ ("lt" -> id) >>> System.out)
```

Here I'm using Dispatch's [JSoup](http://dispatch.databinder.net/JSoup.html) support to parse the form page and pull out the identifier I need, which I can then add to the form parameters when I submit the request.

Comment: Any ideas how to integrate it with Eclipse ? Looks nice, a runned it from command line, but wondering how to do to in Eclipse. Thanks!

Comment: That depends on how you're building the project, etc.—see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6201089/334519) for example for more information.

Comment: When im tryin to use this code i get this: Description Resource Path Location Type
value </> is not a member of dispatch.Request main.scala /default-fa01fe/src/main/scala line 24 Scala Problem

Comment: @daaatz: Are you sure you have both imports? What version of Dispatch are you using?

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this after me, JSoupHttp._ is now being imported as: import dispatch.classic.jsoup.JSoupHttp._

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Apache Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/). Here's tutorial on using it in scala:

http://metacircular.wordpress.com/2007/02/07/towards-polite-http-retrieval-in-scala/

Basically, you:

1. instantiate a httpClient
2. Make a POST request to logowanie.php with username and password params
3. Make the GET request using the same httpClient instance to fetch the page you want